# Steps to use Stripe Connect

Tags: android, ios, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I want to use Stripe Connect in my Android and iOS app. To easily understand the behaviour of the app, it's a sort of marketplace, where some people can publish items and sell them. The publishers must connect with Stripe but I don't have a clear idea of what main steps(or a general scheme) I should take in the implementation. 
I need a diagram from the beginning to the final, included when a publisher post a article and someone buys it. For example:

1. Use the Stripe Connect button
2. Publish the article
3. Save the card in a Card object
4. So on...

Thanks

Comment: Just follow this link and you will get all things. https://stripe.com/docs/mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's [iOS](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and [Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) SDKs fill the same purpose in a native mobile app than [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) and [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) do in a web app: they're used to collect a customer's payment information and turn it into a token, with the data being exchanged directly from the customer's device/browser and Stripe's servers.

Everything else, including using the token to actually create a charge, or, in the case of [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect), connecting accounts to your platform, is done from your backend server, using Stripe's API.

There are two different types of accounts you can use with Connect: [standalone](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts) or [managed](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts). The two are very different, and which one you should use depends on many factors -- [this article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/considerations-for-platforms-using-connect) will help you make the best choice for your use case.

Once you've chosen which types of accounts your platform will use, you will need to implement the appropriate signup flow.

With standalone accounts, you'll want to use the [OAuth flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#oauth-flow) to let users create a Stripe account if they don't already have one, and connect it to your platform.

With managed accounts, you'll need to collect a lot of information about your users and forward it to Stripe to complete the [identity verification process](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification), but you don't have to do it all at once -- you can create managed accounts with minimal information and provide the rest of the information progressively.